# How do I insert a record and put the ID into an existing record in another table?

Tags: postgresql

I want to insert a record in one table and save the resuting ID in a record I already have in another table. Which sounds easy.

Simplistic example:

```
create table aaa (id serial primary key, foo int);
create table foos (id serial primary key, foo int, aaa_id int);
```

Imagine foos has rows which I want to insert in aaa.  But I want a record of `aaa.id` stored in `foos.aaa_id`.

Heres some code that definitely does not work:

```
with rows as (
    insert into aaa (foo) 
        select foo from foos 
        returning foos.id as foos_id, aaa.id as aaa_id 
)
update foos
    set aaa_id = (select aaa_id from rows where foos_id = foos.id);
```

I can't find a way of getting the "returning" clause to return anything other than records from the table it inserted.

Surely there must be a simple way to do this?

Comment: Maybe `UPDATE foos SET aaa_id = (INSERT INTO aaa .... RETURNING id);`?

Comment: @Adam - that would be lovely. But you can only use SELECT there, not INSERT...

Comment: Are you using postgresql < 9.1? See those questions and answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7191902/cannot-select-from-update-returning-clause-in-postgres, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3206951/is-using-the-returning-clause-from-an-update-as-the-query-clause-for-an-inserts.

Comment: @Adam, I'm using 9.5.  It doesn't work, and the docs for 9.5 are quite clear about it.  "column_name = SUB SELECT" right there in the synopsis.  I wish it were otherwise.

Comment: What about using [triggers](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtrigger.html)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use DO block:

```
DO $$
DECLARE
    rows CURSOR FOR
        SELECT * FROM foos;
BEGIN
    FOR r IN rows LOOP
        WITH _ins AS (
            INSERT INTO aaa (foo) 
            VALUES (r.foo)
            RETURNING aaa.id AS aaa_id 
        )
        UPDATE foos
            SET aaa_id = (SELECT aaa_id FROM _ins)
            WHERE id = r.id;
    END LOOP;
END$$;
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have made it clear that I didn't want to use cursors.  I could be doing this in more expressive langages if I wanted to deal with each record one at a time...